# модель данных в Entity Framework: Product->LineProduct->Order

Tags: entity-framework

Доброго времени суток. Начал изучать Entity Framework. и пишу на ASP.net mvc5 пример интернет магазина.
Столкнулся с проблемой построения Доменной модели (точнее связей между сущностями).
Есть сущность Продукт (Product) и заказ (Order). Было бы легко установить между ними связь многие ко многим. Но чтобы избежать дублирование продуктов в заказе нужно ввести еще Количество (LineProduct). LineProduct - это продукт и сколько его заказано (например: Хлеб - 2, Молоко - 10, ...).
Я набросал модель но мне она кажется сложной, ведь задача типовая думаю есть типовое решение.
Таблица Lines мне по сути не нужна. Я заполняю таблицу Products, покупатель формирует Orders. Нужно уметь выбирать все продукты одного заказа и в какие заказы входит выбранный продукт.
Заранее благодарю всех за участие!!!!!

> Products

```
    public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Введите название продукта")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Введите цену продукта")]
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; } 

    public string PictureRef { get; set; }


    public List<Line> Lines { get; set; } = new List<Line>();
}
```

> Lines

```
    public class Line
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Product Product { get; set; }

}
```

> Orders

```
    public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Address DeliveryAddress { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual List<Line> Lines { get; set; } = new List<Line>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Детали заказа я бы наверно вынес в отдельную таблицу `OrderItems`
2. Так как цена товара может измениться со временем, поэтому надо добавить период действия цены(или может даже стоимость вообще вынести в отдельную таблицу) если же история изменения цены не представляет интереса, то при изменении стоимости можно перезаписывать значение в таблице `Product` но тогда я бы в детали заказа добавил цену `public decimal Price {get;set;}`

---

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id {get;set;}        
    public decimal Price {get;set;}
    // прочие поля
}
public class Order
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    // прочие поля

    public virtual ICollection<OrderItems> Items {get;set;}
}
public class OrderItem
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int OrderId {get;set;}
    public int ProductId {get;set;}
    public decimal Amount {get;set;}

    public virtual Order Order {get;set;}
    public virtual Product Product {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Также в таблице Product можно добавить "public virtual ICollection<OrderItems> Items {get;set;}" чтобы достучаться до всех заказов данного продукта. или это делается просто напрямую из таблицы OrderItem? Т.е. поиск  всех элементов по ProductId и соответственно все их заказы.

Comment: @Aldmi dсе заказы для определенного продукта можно получить на основании таблиц `OrderItems` отфильтровав по полю `ProductId` и обратная ситуация когда надо получить все продукты заказа: фильтруем по `OrderId`

Comment: Т.е. это полноценная таблица с которой я работаю через DbSet<OrderItem> OrderItems?